# Add many radio buttons to groupbox C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, loops

I have values in textbox if x I want to show specific number of radio buttons , if y show other specific number of radio buttons so how to add specific number of radio buttons and control its position and size by code, thanks

Comment: WinForms, WPF, something else?

Comment: For WinForms C#

Comment: Have you done any research or attempted to write anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing good old `for` loop. If you want to create radiobuttons being stacked *vertically*:

```
  //TODO: provide the desired value here
  int numberOfRadioButtons = 7;

  //TODO: Put desired values here
  int left = 15;
  int top = 25;
  int height = 50;

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRadioButtons; ++i) {
    RadioButton button = new RadioButton() {
      Parent = myGroupBox,
      Location = new Point(left, top + height * i),
      Text = $"RadioButton # {i}",

      // If you insist on setting size manually, uncomment the lines below
      //AutoSize = false,
      //Size = new Size(200, height),
    };

    // button is created; you can use it, say, to assign event handler:
    //button.Click += MyRadioButtonClick;
  }
```

**Edit:** You can use *Linq* to get *checked* `RadioButton`:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // Either checked rudio button or null if none of radio button is checked
  RadioButton chosen = myGroupBox
    .Controls
    .OfType<RadioButton>()
    .FirstOrDefault(button => button.Checked);
```

Comment: big thanks, but can i get text according to which selected